# how to decode this in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to decode this

```
data = "
8002 7d71 0128 5513 6e75 6d5f 6361 7365
735f 7065 725f 6261 7463 6871 024d 1027
550b 6c61 6265 6c5f 6e61 6d65 7371 035d
7104 2855 0861 6972 706c 616e 6571 0555
0a61 7574 6f6d 6f62 696c 6571 0655 0462
6972 6471 0755 0363 6174 7108 5504 6465
6572 7109 5503 646f 6771 0a55 0466 726f
6771 0b55 0568 6f72 7365 710c 5504 7368
6970 710d 5505 7472 7563 6b71 0e65 5507
6e75 6d5f 7669 7371 0f4d 000c 752e"
```

with :

''.join(chr(int(data[i:i+2],16)) for i in range(0, len(data),2))

and the result is:

```
\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x13num_cases_per_batchq\x02M\x10'U\x0blabel_namesq\x03]q\x04(U\x08airplaneq\x05U\nautomobileq\x06U\x04birdq\x07U\x03catq\x08U\x04deerq\tU\x03dogq\nU\x04frogq\x0bU\x05horseq\x0cU\x04shipq\rU\x05truckq\x0eeU\x07num_visq\x0fM\x00\x0cu."
```

this is the class names of cifar 10 database, I understand the names like

```
airplane
automobile
bird
cat
deer
dog
frog
horse
ship
truck
```

but i don´t know the meaning of

```
\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x13
 q\x02M\x10'U\x0b...
 and so on...
```

I need to convert my own words in this format but I don´t understand the "words"

Thanks!

Comment: The version of python is 2.7.12

Comment: You need to tell us what kind of encoding we are looking at and please show us the code you have so far. If you don't know what this is encoded in, the [cryptography community](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pickle:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> print(pickle.loads('''\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x13num_cases_per_batchq\x02M\x10'U\x0blabel_namesq\x03]q\x04(U\x08airplaneq\x05U\nautomobileq\x06U\x04birdq\x07U\x03catq\x08U\x04deerq\tU\x03dogq\nU\x04frogq\x0bU\x05horseq\x0cU\x04shipq\rU\x05truckq\x0eeU\x07num_visq\x0fM\x00\x0cu."'''))
{'num_cases_per_batch': 10000, 'label_names': ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'], 'num_vis': 3072}
```

Comment: how I can convert the output {'num_cases_per_batch': 10000, 'label_names': ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck'], 'num_vis': 3072}

Comment: @ZelDrums I don't know what you mean. `pickle.loads(thestring)` gives you a nice dictionary. What more do you want?

Comment: I need convert the output that you give me in the input that I give you, how can i do it?

Comment: `data = ''.join(chr(int(data[i:i+2],16)) for i in range(0, len(data),2)); data = pickle.loads(data)`. Now `data` is a dictionary. `data['label_names'] is a list of words. I still don't understand what else you need. I don't know what "I need convert the output that you give me in the input that I give you" means.

Comment: If I want to convert  {'num_cases_per_batch': 10000, 'label_names':........ in 8002 7d71 0128 5513 6e75 6d5f 6361 7365 ..... how can I do it?

Comment: To convert an object back to a string encoded with pickle, use `pickle.dumps(obj)`. I'll let you figure out converting back to the hexadecimal format.